# GA - GT Event value not coming through with decimal places

Tags: google-analytics

For some reason when I gt event values through to analytics it comes through without a decimal place.

They way I track the event is on the site after conversion I use the datalayer to send the amount data via tag manager to the corresponding places.

The amount is a custom variable setup in tag manager and feeds to a few different locations like Bing conversion tracking and Adwords Conversion tracking as well as my goal and event tracking within analytics. What I have noticed though is for some reason in analytics my event values are coming through minus the decimal space.

so for instance if my conv value was 5.68 it comes through as 5 in analytics event value.

Anyone had any similar issues in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround here is to set the value in a more granular unit (e.g. cents instead of dollars). In your example you would set the value to 568 instead of 5.68

**Warning**: value should be exactly Integer, not 568.0 - same events will skipped GA.

Comment: When doing this, is there a way to convert it back into a decimal for ingestion by google ads, bing ads, etc.?  Otherwise all those earnings and return on spend reports in those platforms will be incorrect.

Comment: @NathanStretch You should take a look at Calculated Metrics. Which is currently in Beta.